# D3 Brush coordinates under CSS transform scale

Tags: css, d3.js, transform, scale, brush

D3 brush does not function properly under css transform scale.   When svg is under div element, and div element is transformed using CSS scale, the brush operation shows wrong coordinates.

To demonstrate this case, here is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/intuinno/5cpgkqhu/2/).

It is simple modification from [Bostock's Brushable Network example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4560481).

What I did was simply putting SVG in the div element and made div element zoom 50% using CSS transform scale(0.5).  And the brushing coordinates are not updating because of zooming.

```
#test {
transform: scale(0.5);
}
```

Thanks.

Deok

Comment: You can find the similar issue for single mouse event [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/d3-js/EYnbizCA3LM). It suggests the use of the following code to transform between original coordinates.

But it would be great if somebody can point the appropriate approach for the brush event.

Comment: Your jsfiddle is giving me an error.

Comment: I am sorry the correct link is http://jsfiddle.net/intuinno/5cpgkqhu/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use an svg based transform:

```
transform="scale(0.5)"
```

Then it'll play nice with the brush:

```
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

svg = svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform","scale(0.5)");
```

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5cpgkqhu/4/).

To fix the calculations you need two things.

1.) Scale the extent rect opposite the div:

```
.extent {
   transform: scale(2);
}
```

2.) Fix the extent calculations:

```
   .on("brush", function() {
      var extent = d3.event.target.extent();
      node.classed("selected", function(d) {
        return extent[0][0] <= d.x && d.x < extent[1][0] && 
               extent[0][1] <= (d.y/2) && (d.y/2) < extent[1][1]; // scale y opposite div transform
      });
   });
```

New example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/g54WVKv55Ebb5emea4gb?p=preview).

Comment: Thank you for your kind answer.  However I don't have access to the svg due to the settings in my project.  So I am looking for the solution for the css based transform.

Comment: @intuinno, don't have access to the svg?  if you leave the transform in CSS, you'll have to take it into account int he brush calculations.

Comment: Yes.  It sounds strange that I don't have an access to the svg.  My situation is I am using d3 visualization inside the jsplumb object.  The jsplumb object handles the scaling on the div using css transform.  I have to brush some region on the svg in the div.  So I can't apply your solution. Would you please let me know about more taking it into the brush calculation?

Comment: @intuinno, see new answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you use CSS transform you should apply it to all the classes that related by nodes:

```
 .node {
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
  transform: scale(0.5);
 }

 .node .selected {
        stroke: red;
  }

.link {
   stroke: #999;
     transform: scale(0.5);
  }

.brush .extent {
  fill-opacity: .1;
  stroke: #fff;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
  transform: scale(0.5);
}
```

When you add `transform: scale(0.5);` you can brush all the node. Try from **left to right** over node position.

```
 var width = 960,height = 500;
  var svg = d3.select("#body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height);


    graph.links.forEach(function(d) {
        d.source = graph.nodes[d.source];
        d.target = graph.nodes[d.target];
    });

    var link = svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "link")
        .selectAll("line")
        .data(graph.links)
        .enter().append("line")
        .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

    var node = svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "node")
        .selectAll("circle")
        .data(graph.nodes)
        .enter().append("circle")
        .attr("r", 4)
        .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });

    var brush = svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "brush")
        .call(d3.svg.brush()
            .x(d3.scale.identity().domain([0, width]))
            .y(d3.scale.identity().domain([0, height]))
            .on("brush", function() {
                var extent = d3.event.target.extent();
                node.classed("selected", function(d) {
                    return extent[0][0] <= d.x && d.x < extent[1][0]
                        && extent[0][1] <= d.y && d.y < extent[1][1];
                });
            }));
```

Complete jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/zzjebraeil/eqry2hL9/).

Comment: Thank you for an answer.  However I am not sure you shared correct jsfiddle link.  In the jsfiddle, you shared, the bug is still there.  Would you please check again?  Thansk.

Comment: It's the correct link, cause of the `domain([0, width])` the best brush is from left to right. start from the left position and drag to right position of page the brush will work correctly.

Comment: No, in my opinion, the brush coordinates are slightly different from the mouse position.  I think this does not solve the problem of brush with css transform.  I am sorry.