# Drag not working properly after applying scale transform on force layout

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I have a project built on top of the following force layout. I have my entire elements appended inside the root SVG similar to this.

I'm trying to apply zoom on the same now. Since I cannot have a wrapping `g` tag, I'm trying to apply scale transform on `SVG`. Although it gets zoomed, the drag behavior is improper. The point at which the mouse appears and the element appears are different.

```js
graph =  {
  "nodes": [
    {"x": 469, "y": 410},
    {"x": 493, "y": 364},
    {"x": 442, "y": 365},
    {"x": 467, "y": 314},
    {"x": 477, "y": 248},
    {"x": 425, "y": 207},
    {"x": 402, "y": 155},
    {"x": 369, "y": 196},
    {"x": 350, "y": 148},
    {"x": 539, "y": 222},
    {"x": 594, "y": 235},
    {"x": 582, "y": 185},
    {"x": 633, "y": 200}
  ],
  "links": [
    {"source":  0, "target":  1},
    {"source":  1, "target":  2},
    {"source":  2, "target":  0},
    {"source":  1, "target":  3},
    {"source":  3, "target":  2},
    {"source":  3, "target":  4},
    {"source":  4, "target":  5},
    {"source":  5, "target":  6},
    {"source":  5, "target":  7},
    {"source":  6, "target":  7},
    {"source":  6, "target":  8},
    {"source":  7, "target":  8},
    {"source":  9, "target":  4},
    {"source":  9, "target": 11},
    {"source":  9, "target": 10},
    {"source": 10, "target": 11},
    {"source": 11, "target": 12},
    {"source": 12, "target": 10}
  ]
}

var width = 960,
    height = 500;

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .size([width, height])
    .charge(-400)
    .linkDistance(40)
    .on("tick", tick);

var drag = force.drag()
    .on("dragstart", dragstart);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var link = svg.selectAll(".link"),
    node = svg.selectAll(".node");



  force
      .nodes(graph.nodes)
      .links(graph.links)
      .start();

  link = link.data(graph.links)
    .enter().append("line")
      .attr("class", "link");

  node = node.data(graph.nodes)
    .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("r", 12)
      .on("dblclick", dblclick)
      .call(drag);


function tick() {
  link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
      .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
      .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
      .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

  node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
      .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
}

function dblclick(d) {
  d3.select(this).classed("fixed", d.fixed = false);
}

function dragstart(d) {
  d3.select(this).classed("fixed", d.fixed = true);
}
```

```css
.link {
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.node {
  cursor: move;
  fill: #ccc;
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.node.fixed {
  fill: #f00;
}

svg{
  transform:scale(2);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.2/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: `Since I cannot have a wrapping g tag`; why?

Comment: Here's a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31300244/16363) I answered sometime ago.

Comment: @Mark this is part of a larger project. I have lot of events and functions done based on the wrapper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can  use svg viewBox [viewport, viewBox, and preserveAspectRatio](https://sarasoueidan.com/blog/svg-coordinate-systems/)

It talking about the use of viewbox

Comment: This was the solution I was looking for. Thanks.